Solving Abel equation of the second kind
I am absolutely not familiar with differential equations. However, I am facing the following non-linear variable coefficient ordinary differential equation:
\begin{equation}
a(x)y^{3}(x) + b(x)y^{2}(x) + c(x)y(x) + [d(x)y(x) + e(x)]y^{\prime}(x) + g(x) = 0
\end{equation}
or written differently
\begin{equation}
y^{\prime}(x) = \frac{a(x)y^{3}(x) + b(x)y^{2}(x) + c(x)y(x) + g(x)}{\tilde{d}(x)y(x) + \tilde{e}(x)}
\end{equation}
I checked Zwillinger's handbook on differential equation and Handbook of exact solutions for ordinary differential equations by Andrei Polyanin and Valentin Zaitsev in the hope to find differential equations having a similar form. The closest I got was the structure of an Abel equation of the second kind, I guess.
I tried to solve this equation using MATLAB using the following code:
syms x a(x) b(x) c(x) d(x) e(x) f(x) g(x) y(x)
num = a(x)*y^(3) + b(x)*y^(2) + c(x)*y + g(x);
denom = d(x)*y(x) + e(x);
ode = (diff(y,x) == num/denom)
ySol(x) = dsolve(ode)

however, this did not result in a solution. I do not know how to proceed. Can you help me making the next steps or pointing me even to the solution? Thank you very much.

No ODE this general and nonlinear has closed form solutions. You may want to specialize the problem or solve numerically.

thanks for your feedback!

... or seek solutions in series. BTW, Maple calls this Abel's equation of the second kind, class C.

thank you for this hint!
